# Notepad HTML not open file:// links

Tags: html, macos, safari, jwplayer

I'm using the following code in Notepad HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Youtube Player Test</title>
<script src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/eVB7ZSqv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_LR5XHyFSc",
    width: 640,
    height: 360
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but on line 4, and 11, the links are opening as: file://... however, I want it to run it externally, not locally?

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (iframe_api, line 0) file://www.youtube.com/iframe_api
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (0.jpg, line 0) file://i.ytimg.com/vi/n_LR5XHyFSc/0.jpg
```

Thats the error I get in the dev console.

P.S I'm using mac/safari.

Comment: Probably not relevant to the problem, but give the page a proper DOCTYPE.

Comment: looks familiar. I think I came across a similar issue a couple of months ago. Basically when JW parses youtube links it replaces 'http' with whatever protocol was used to load the html page and since it's a local file in your case it's being replaced with 'file://'. If i'm right there is nothing you can do about it - try contacting JW support.

Answer (score 1):

It is making external calls beyond your file system. You have given them external links. This seems to work fine on Jsbin as shown [here](http://jsbin.com/jowosuseyi/edit?html,css,output). What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve? It maybe the way you saved the file locally.

Comment: The problem is when I use jsfiddle, or jsbin I get:

 Blocked a frame with origin "http://null.jsbin.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsbin.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match... and the video doesn't load either.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here relates to trying to use the HTML5 mode with YouTube, which invokes some weird iframe nonsense. Here's what works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>JW Player</title>
<script src='jwplayer.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='myElement'>Loading the player...</div>
<script>
    jwplayer('myElement').setup({
        file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj-7LxpF9dA',
        primary: 'flash',
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm self-hosting the scripts (there's really no reason to be pulling them from the JW site - why introduce another potential failure point?). Other differences: https for the video, Flash mode as the primary.

Finally, to run it on your own hard drive (truly local - not even a localhost), you need to add your hard drive to the "trusted locations" for Flash: System Preferences, Flash Player, Advanced, Developer Tools, Trusted Location Settings, add your own HD.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are running this locally, not in a local web server. If you use MAMP for example or XMAPP for Windows, this will work fine.